# Building Qt6 project - QMAKE_CXX.COMPILER_MACROS not defined

Tags: qt, cmake, qmake, qt6

I'm building a Qt6 project using the following command

`~/Qt/6.3.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake -o ~/nidb/bin/smtp/Makefile ~/nidb/src/smtp/SMTPEmail.pro -spec linux-g++`

And it generates this error...

`~/Qt/6.3.1/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf:76: Variable QMAKE_CXX.COMPILER_MACROS is not defined.`

This used to work fine on my Rocky Linux 8 machine, but now it's not working. I ran a yum update at some point in the last few weeks, but that's the only thing I can think of that changed.
What are some other reasons it might have stopped working?

Comment: Do you build it using Qt Creator? It should give you a default qmake command that should work. If it doesn't work, maybe your install is broken?

Comment: I tested that and it doesn't build using Qt Creator either... it used to, but not anymore. I wonder what happened to my Qt install. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Is the build directory clean?
Do you have a .qmake.stash file lying around in ~, ~/nidb, ~/nidb/bin, ~/nidb/bin/smtp, ~/nidb/src or ~/nidb/src/smtp?  If yes, try again after deleting it.

Comment: There were some .stash files, but I removed those. And I've actually removed all of the directories within ~/nidb/bin. Still the same error. I have tried completely uninstalling Qt, rebooting, and reinstalling Qt. But I suspect there is some vestige of Qt in the system because when I run the installer again, it has prefilled my Qt login info.

Comment: I'm still running into this error unfortunately. I wasn't able to get my installation of Qt to work, so I built an entirely new VM and migrated the source code. After a few weeks of things working correctly, it stopped working again. Uninstalling/reinstalling Qt doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I have this same issue when building in an amd64 Debian Docker image in Mac M2 (using rosetta, building the Docker image with  "--platform linux/amd64"). When I use the exact same Dockerfile but build using Debian arm, it builds without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just answering my own question in case anyone else encounters this bug themselves.

My issue was that the RHEL/CentOS/Rocky 8.6 kernel had a bug which didn't work correctly with QProcess. After doing a yum update, it updated the kernel and then I encountered the error. The error was that QProcess did not return any output, so any programs requiring console output to decide on the next step, would fail.

At the time downgrading the kernel fixed it for me. But the kernel bug was fixed in 8.7 releases and newer.